# Why MapFragment(HERE-API) extends android.app.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, sdk, here-api

Why MapFragment(HERE-API) extends `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

If you have a structure to maintain compatibility with oldest versions of Android you will need to change!

For example: if you have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` you can't use `MapFragment`!! Because `FragmentPagerAdapter` uses support.v4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the FragmentPagerAdapter from the v13 support library:

[`android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
}
```